# Cannot send formdata using post request

Tags: angular, post

I'm trying to send a form data with a file using POST request in Angular 4. If the header is `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` the form data does not send to the server. If the header is `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`, the client side can send the form data to the server. But in postman application/json will work. I want the same in Angular 4.

Component.ts:
`

```
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append("courseId", this.course_id.toString());
        formData.append("courseName", this.course_name.toString());
        formData.append('pic', this.file);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers,withCredentials: true  });
        this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/createNew', formData, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log('success'),
                error => console.log(error)
            )`
```

Html:

```
<input type="file" name="pic" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
<input type="button" value="Upload" (click)="onUpload()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The`'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` header tells the browser that the content of the request should not be encoded. You need this for example when a form requires binary data, like the contents of a file.

Its  likely that postman ignores/removes the `application/json` one.

Answer (score 2):

To submit `formdata` in angular or anywhere, the content type of the should not be a `Json`.
So you can do like this :

```
 let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append("courseId", this.course_id.toString());
    formData.append("courseName", this.course_name.toString());
    formData.append('pic', this.file);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers,withCredentials: true  });
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/createNew', formData, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log('success'),
            error => console.log(error)
        )`
```